# Get Find results in Word (Save a set of successive Word Find results for later use)

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm trying to write a Word Add-In that searches the document for a specific text, highlights its occurrences, and enables the user to skip from one occurrence to the next.

I've succeeded with the first two tasks (searching and highlighting), but I couldn't find a way to store the locations of the results, so the user can skip between them.

The Find method returns bool, and I couldn't find any info regarding the count of the occurrences, and their location.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var range=Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range();
var find = range.Find;
find.HitHighlight("My Text");            
bool found = find.Found;
```

So how can I get the result of Find?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Word API documentation for [Find Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192204%28v=office.14%29.aspx) I do not see any method that returns a the list of results, so I do not believe you can do what you want.

Maybe I am misunderstanding your point of creating this add-in, but you can do the functionality you describe inside of Word already, via the Advanced Find. So what is the point of your add-in?

Comment: My point is that I want to create a search algorithm that is different from the one in Word.

Answer (score 0):

Almost 10 years later, but I recently ran into a need to do the same thing as the OP.....

When you want to execute a series of Word Find commands and want to later let the user set the cursor to the location of the previous Find(s), all you really need to store at the time you do each Find is the start and end range values associated with each Find result. Then, at a later point in your program, you can create a Range object, load the previously stored start range value and end range value, and navigate to that location in the document using the reconstituted Range object.

*Note: This presumes the user did not edit the document after the start and end range values associated with each Find result were stored. If that's a possibility, then you'll need to provide a way for the user to redo the Find(s) before letting the user attempt to navigate to the locations.*

Here's the general idea. This is Word VSTO add-in code for a scenario where I want the find to not use wildcards and ignore whitespace in the found text. Untested, not compiled, but extracted from a working VSTO add-in.

Final note: I didn't try this, but the Word `Range` object provides a [Duplicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.duplicate) property. By duplicating a Range object, you can, for example, change the starting or ending character position of the duplicate range without changing the original range, e.g., `Word.Range copyOfRangeObject = wordRange.Duplicate;` It ***may be*** you use this to build an array or list of found Range(s)

```
// Example from a Word VSTO add-in program

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document_ActiveDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range wordRange = null;

// list and class to store start and range end values

IList<RangeMetadata> rangeMetadataList = new List<RangeMetadata>();

public class RangeMetadata
{
    int rangeStart;
    public RangeStart { get => rangeStart; set => rangeStart = value; }
    
    int rangeEnd;
    public RangeEnd { get => rangeEnd; set => rangeEnd = value; }
    
    public class RangeMetadata(int rangeStart, int rangeEnd)
    {
        RangeStart = rangeStart;
        RangeEnd = rangeEnd;
    }
}

// Code for Word Find

string yourFindText = "foo";

wordRange = document_ActiveDoc.Content;
wordRange.Find.ClearFormatting();
wordRange.Find.IgnoreSpace = true;

// Prime the pump Find
wordRange.Find.Execute(FindText: yourFindText, MatchWildcards: false, Forward: true);

while (wordRange.Find.Found)
{
    // Note: you can obtain the Find range page number. Might be useful to the user
    int pageNumber = wordRange.get_Information(WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber);
    
    RangeMetadata rangeMetadata = new RangeMetadata(wordRange.Start, wordRange.End);
    
    rangeMetadataList.Add(rangeMetadata);
    
    // Next Find
    wordRange.Find.Execute(FindText: yourFindText, MatchWildcards: false, Forward: true);
}

// code to set the cursor on previous find(s) using a range

foreach (RangeMetadata rmd in rangeMetadataList)
{
    Word.Range rng = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(rmd.RangeStart, rmd.RangeEnd); 

    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView(rng, true);

    // to select the found text
    rng.Select();

    // optional to de-select and leave the cursor at the beginning of the found text
    //object direction = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart;
    //Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Collapse(ref direction);
}
```